# Custom checkbox not accepting the click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [bootstrap custom checkbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons)

And I am generating images with checkboxes to select each image to remove them:

```
<div class="card">
    <img alt="Jiku <?php $altTitle = get_the_title(); echo $altTitle; ?>" class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo $ximage[0]; ?>" srcset="<?php echo $img_srcset; ?>" sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 720px, 360px">
    <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="selected deleteImg" name="image<?php echo $imagenum; ?>" value="<?php echo $image->ID; ?>">  Delete
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I use some jquery to handle the remove, this is part of it just to provide the idea..

```
   $('.deleteImg').click(function(e) {
      $(this).attr("checked");
      $('#ids').val('');
      var content = $('body').find('.selected');
      $(content).each(function (i) {
          t = $(this).val();
          if ($(this).attr('checked')=='checked') { 
              $('#ids').val(function(i,val) {
                  return val + t + ',';
              }); 
          };
      });

      var $ids = $('#ids').val();
```

But it only works If i remove the `label` but unfortunatly the label is what provides the custom style, why isn't it accepting the click on the input, am I wrongly targetting with jQuery?

Working example, without label:

```
<div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="selected deleteImg" name="image<?php echo $imagenum; ?>" value="<?php echo $image->ID; ?>">  Delete
</div>
```

Comment: If possible it might be useful to set this up in https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the **click** event on the checkbox to a **change** event like this:

```
$('.deleteImg').change(function (e) {
    $(this).attr("checked");
    $('#ids').val('');
    var content = $('body').find('.selected');
    $(content).each(function (i) {
        t = $(this).val();
        if ($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked') {
            $('#ids').val(function (i, val) {
                return val + t + ',';
            });
        };
    });
    var $ids = $('#ids').val();
});
```

Comment: Yup, that was it. Just that I know, why the click wasn't working?